# Vtune Memory Leak helper

Tags: python, memory-leaks, intel-vtune

I am using VTune to take memory statics for my app memory leak detection.

My Python app have a memory steady increase, it turns out there are "make_new_set" calls which keep creating python arena and seems cause memory leak.

But after my code inspected and other methods like using objgraph to detect growth, i still cannot find its origin.

So if there are any methods to find the origin?
[image: vtune profile]

Answer (score 0):

While running memory consumption analysis in VTune, memory allocation/deallocation delta can be gathered but a deeper code analysis is required to observe any memory leaks. From the below example, the python foo function allocated 915 310 048 bytes of memory in a call tree displayed in the Call Stack pane on the right but released only 817 830 048 bytes. 92MB is the maximum Allocation/Deallocation delta value that signals a potential memory leak. Clicking the foo function opens the Source view highlighting the code line that allocates the maximum memory.
[image]

So, Rather than using VTune for capturing memory leaks, it would be easy to use Intel Inspector.

Intel Inspector customarily displays memory leaks at the end of an analysis run when an application exits; however, you can also use the Intel Inspector on-demand memory leak detection feature to gather memory leak information while an application is running.

Get more information [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/inspector-user-guide-linux/top/collecting-results/examining-result-data-during-analysis/finding-memory-leaks-on-demand.html)!
For installing Intel Inspector, click [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/inspector.html)